# ¿Cómo editar css con JavaScript, de esta forma...?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, dom

He encontrado muchas formas de editar css con JavaScript; pero no encontré una forma directa de agregar una propiedad a css. ¿Cómo modifico o agrego una propiedad directamente a mi class item ? ¿o no es posible?. por ejemplo en el css de la etiqueta div.

```html
<div id="box" class="item"></div>
```

```css
.item{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:green;
display:block;

}
```

como incluir un position:absolute; en la class "item" o modificar  display:block;  a
display:flex;

esta demás decir que soy un principiante en javascript, gracias.

Comment: Para hacerlo con el classname, tendrías que recorrer cada elemento de clase item que tengas. Si usaras el ID sería sencillo cambiar solo uno.

Comment: @kraud no puedes modificar css desde javascript. Pero lo que si que puedes hacer es crear diferentes clases y en javascript poner o quitar clases a un div. O la otra manera pero menos usada o mas chapucera es crearle una propiedad 'style', y poner todo el css en linea.

Te acosnejo el de canviar las clases es el que todo los frameworks usan si te das cuenta al hacer click en algun sitio

Comment: @JordiTurell de donde sacas que no puedes ???

Comment: Puedes cambiar un archivo css desde un JS ?

Comment: @kraud ¿Te [fijaste](/q/74138) en [estas](/q/234723/) [preguntas](/q/223840/)? (Y hay varias más en el sitio).

Comment: @JordiTurell eso no es lo que el está preguntando. El dice claramente "editar el css con javascript"

Comment: gracias por comentar, y orientarme; encontré este que me funciono. document.querySelector(".item").style.display= "none";

Comment: @JordiTurell si es posible modificar el archivo css desde JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cualquier selector que pueda devolver mas de un elemento es necesario iterarlo y cambiar cada uno.

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("item")].
forEach(e => e.style["background-color"] = "blue")
```

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="item"></div>
```

Hay una palabra en la pregunta que genera cierta confusión, "editar". Es posible "editar" los estilos definidos en una hoja de estilos en el sentido estricto, usando `.insertRule`, aunque no me parece conveniente para este caso, dejo un ejemplo de como sería posible:

```js
const estilos = document.styleSheets[0];

console.log(estilos.cssRules[0].cssText); // <-- viejo


estilos.deleteRule(0);
estilos.insertRule('.item { width:200px; height:200px; background-color:blue; display:block; }', 0);

console.log(estilos.cssRules[0].cssText); // <-- nuevo
```

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Basado en lo que muestra OP, probablemente sería suficiente crear una nueva regla para `#box.item` y no es necesario modificar la original. +1.

Comment: Si, es mejor crear una regla nueva, pero quería mostrar la mecánica de "editar" una regla existente, hasta donde tengo entendido hay que reemplazar todo el selector.

Comment: @Emeeus gracias por tu respuesta, cuando dije "editar directamente" no fui preciso, me refería que cuando se edite alguna propiedad de una clase, los cambios solo se manifiesten en el class; ya sea en el archivo css o dentro del atributo class="" del html.

Comment: aceptare esta respuesta como solución, por aclarar el tema  gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

algo asi ?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("item").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementsByClassName("item").style.display = "flex";
```

Tambien soy relativamente nuevo en js, Saludos.

Comment: Correcto, pero para responder correctamente tienes que explicar como y que hacer. Te recomiendo leer [answer] para que sepas como hacerlo bien ;)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Lee [answer]: debes explicar brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda que este sitio _no es un repositorio de código_, por lo tanto se busca que el usuario no se limite netamente a copiarlo, sino a comprender su funcionamiento. Además, ten en cuenta que la pregunta probablemente sea una duplicada de varias otras ya existentes en el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

respondiendo mi propia pregunta.

```
<div id="box" class="item"></div>

.item{
width:200px;
height:200px;

display:block;

}
```

encontré esto para modificar una propiedad: por ejemplo display `document.querySelector(".item").style.display= "none"`;  eso ara que el elemento div no se muestre.

ahora para agregar una propiedad que no esta en la class item usare el id="box":

```
let box= document.getElementById('box');
box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

eso ara que el div tome el color rojo.
No se si habrá otra forma, de hacer esto, seguiré leyendo...  gracias! a todos por comentar mi pregunta.

Comment: woow! el querySelector es increíble, no solo modifica una propiedad sino tambien puede incluir una propiedad dentro de la clase.   ya no tengo que aplicar un estilo en linea; sino simplemente: document.querySelector(".item").style.backgroundColor= "red" ; busca la clase .item y le agrega background-color: red;

Comment: Con este código no modificas la clase, sino el elemento seleccionado por `querySelector()` y, si revisas el elemento con el inspector del navegador, verás que se agregan estilos en línea. En caso de tener múltiples elementos de la misma clase, deberás usar `querySelectorAll()` y recorrer con un ciclo para modificar las propiedades deseadas a todos.

Comment: @Triby tienes razón, al menos no le agrego estilo en linea de forma explicita en el código html. me encantaría editar la clase directamente; pero por ahora solo tengo esta forma.  la verdad, no estoy seguro de que se pueda editar la clase directamente...

Answer (score 0):

Creo, no estoy seguro, lo recomendable seria usar clases diferentes si quieres cambiar una propiedad de forma dinámica y usar el código de la siguiente forma:

```js
document.getElementById("box").classList.remove("tipo1");
document.getElementById("box").classList.add("tipo2");
```

```css
.item{
width:200px;
height:200px;

display:block;

}
.tipo1{
background-color: green;
}
.tipo2{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="item tipo1"></div>
```

"Y al revisar con el inspector no aparece el estilo en linea que tanto quería evitar"